# What statistical test should I use for my dataset?

Tags: variance, categorical-data

I am trying to analyse my data for my research.

I distributed a 10 question questionnaire with response option yes no or maybe and also asked the respondents to select ethnicity (from 6 categories)

I now want to analyse my responses and find if there is a statistical difference to each ethnicity's response to each question to identify if certain groups feel differently about certain questions however I am VERY rusty with statistics so don't really know where to start.

I could just compare percentage of each group's yes response if that is simpler...

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test